# Set a timeout before show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a problem, I want to show a div after 5 seconds, I tried :

```
if(obj.google_analytics.is_casino_game){
  setTimeout(function() { }, 500);
}
document.getElementById('addsense-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
```

But does not work. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it, but you have to at least put the code you want executed inside the timeout

```
if(obj.google_analytics.is_casino_game){
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('addsense-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
    }, 5000);
}
```

Note that hiding and showing ads from adSense in this way is generally considered breaking the TOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delay`:

```
if (obj.google_analytics.is_casino_game) {
    $('#addsense-pub').delay(5000).show();
    // Will add delay of 5 seconds before showing the element
}
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

**OR**

Using `setTimeout`:

```
if (obj.google_analytics.is_casino_game) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#addsense-pub').show();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code inside setTimeout function()

```
 setTimeout(function() { 
   $('#addsense-pub').show();

}, 5000);
```